# Histogram and Random Lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, histograms

Suppose I have the following list `listrand` of random numbers from `RandomReal[-30,30]` (where the size of the list is 40). Is there a way to create a histogram of `listrand` where we count the amount of elements between $[-30,-25]$, $[-25,-20]$, ..., $[25,30]$ (intervals of size $5$) present in the list? (the bars having as width these intervals, and the height of a bar being the amount of elements in `listrand` that fall between this specific interval).

As well, is it possible to generalize this procedure for more complicated examples? (say, where the size of the intervals is an irrational number)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Btw, I'm voting to close this question because it can really easily be found in the documentation.

Comment: See the [Histogram documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html?q=Histogram) , Details section, specifically the *bspec* description.

Answer (score 2):

The bin-sizes (which is what you *interval sizes*) can be specified directly in `Histogram`:

```
Histogram[RandomReal[-30, 40], {5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Btw, it's funny when you say

> random numbers from `RandomReal[-30,30]` (where the size of the list is **40**)

and you just specified to get a list with 30 random numbers :-)

Edit: Ahh, and now I see why you said it. When you want random numbers between [-30,30] and you want 40 of them, then the correct call is

```
RandomReal[{-30, 30}, 40]
```

which leaves us with

[image: Mathematica graphics]